# How to attach gdb to stripped sshd server?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, debug-symbols, sshd

I want to debug ssh server running on my Linux mint.. sshd running on my machine do not have debug symbols in it(Stripped binary). As per my knowledge, there exists a way to download debug symbol image corresponding to sshd. Is there any way to attach gdb to sshd with debug symbols image ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to install debug symbols that are shipped separately:

```
sudo debuginfo-install openssh
```

And then you can simply attach to running process, such as:

```
gdb --pid `pidof sshd`
```